# Can anyone advise on string replacement in pandas dataframe column names using re.sub()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem with a valid dataframe, df, that contains in the column names characters such as '_', ' ', '?', and '-'. The dataframe is imported from a third party csv. I need to get rid of those characters so:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
```

.
.
.
define df
.
.
.

```
dfr = [(' ', '_'), ('?', ''), ('/', '_'), ('-', '_')]
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_') ¦ *these four*   
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('?', '')  ¦ *lines are*
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('/', '_') ¦ *my original*
# df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('-', '_') ¦ *functioning code*
for o, n in dfr:
    df.columns = re.sub(o, n, df.columns.str)
```

This produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 33, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\andyt\anaconda3\envs\Property\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Can someone help?

### Column names in response to @sammywemmy:

```
c = ['Postcode', 'In Use?', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Easting', 'Northing', 'Grid Ref', 'County',
                          'District', 'Ward', 'Country', 'Constituency', 'Introduced', 'Terminated', 'Parish',
                          'National Park', 'Population', 'Households', 'Built up area', 'Built up sub-division',
                          'Lower layer super output area', 'Rural/urban', 'Region', 'Altitude', 'London zone',
                          'Local authority', 'Middle layer super output area', 'Index of Multiple Deprivation',
                          'Quality', 'User Type', 'Last updated', 'Nearest station', 'Distance to station',
                          'Police force', 'Water company', 'Plus Code', 'Average Income']
```

### Update in response to @AMC

So in response to @AMC here is a **reprex:**

original code:

```
import pandas as pd, re

df = pd.DataFrame({'In Use?':[False,False], 
                   'Built up sub-division':['<NA>','<NA>'], 
                   'Rural/urban':['Accessible small town','Accessible small town']})

print (df)
```

this produces the following dataframe:

```
   In Use? Built up sub-division            Rural/urban
0    False                  <NA>  Accessible small town
1    False                  <NA>  Accessible small town
```

wanting to substitute for the following characters in the column names: `' ', '-', '?' and '/'`, I added the following:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_') #¦ *these four*
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('?', '')  #¦ *lines are*
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('/', '_') #¦ *my original*
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('-', '_') #¦ *functioning code*
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
   In_Use Built_up_sub_division            Rural_urban
0   False                  <NA>  Accessible small town
1   False                  <NA>  Accessible small town
```

however, wanting to write neater code I decided to substitute the following for the four `df.columns.str.replace` calls:

```
dfr = [(' ', '_'), ('?', ''), ('/', '_'), ('-', '_')]
for o, n in dfr:
    df.columns = re.sub(o, n, df.columns.str)
```

This poduces the error first stated, i.e.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 33, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\andyt\anaconda3\envs\Property\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

#### @AMC also asked what I understand from that error...

The answer is that it seems that the **re.sub** module wants a string passed as the third argument (I have debugged this by individually assigning `o = ' '` and `n = '_'` in place of the dictionary assignment at `dfr = ...` and the error persists) but I do not see how 'df.columns.str' can act as a string in `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')` but not in `df.columns = re.sub(o, n, df.columns.str)`.

Comment: pandas ```str replace``` is built on ```re.sub```, and ```str.replace``` , so depending on ur use case, u might have to set regex=True,

Comment: do u mind sharing ur df.columns?

Comment: sorry @sammywemmy, where would I set regex=True? Only 2 weeks into pandas and python

Comment: [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) u insert regex in the parameters

Comment: my original lines using replace are functioning (see commented out code) - there is no regex parameter in the re.sub documentation: `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your line:

```
df.columns = re.sub(o, n, df.columns.str)
```

with

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(o,n)
```

and you're good!

Comment: Thank you!!!! Still don't see why the re.sub call didn't work but of no consequence to me now